# Travelling near the speed of light

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

Suppose that there is a long straight board held horizontal to the ground, and it is released from rest.
If I were to travel at 0.9c past the board (from one end to the other), would I perceive both ends of the board to fall simultaneously? Or will I see one end of the board reach the ground faster than the other?

Comment: You see the the board starting to fall propagating as a sound wave propagating at the specific speed of sound for the given material. Plus some length contraction and you will calculate the speed of sound differently then you would of you did this from a slower reference frame

Comment: To answer questions like this for yourself, learn about spacetime diagrams and how to construct them.

Comment: @AndrewSteane:  You're mostly right of course but this particular problem involves two spatial dimensions, not just one, so "draw the diagram", taken literally, is perhaps not the best advice.  It is, of course, pretty much morally equivalent to the best advice, though.

Answer (score 1):

If both ends are released simultaneously in your frame, they will hit the ground simultaneously in your frame.  If they are released simultaneously in the ground frame, they will hit  the ground simultaneously in the ground frame, hence not in yours.

Comment: This is a good answer. "Simultaneous" is a frame dependent thing: there is no universal absolute time, only relative time.

Answer (score 0):

In order to tackle this problem, one would first model the dimensions of the board at time t relative to the observer. Then one would model the propagation of light bouncing off the board and reaching the observers eye.

In step 1, we obviously have length contraction of the board which acts in one dimension since the downwards speed is non relativistic.

In step 2, we must consider that light emitted from the back of the board will take ever so slightly longer than light emitted from the front of the board to reach the observer's eye. Therefore the back of the board will be slightly higher in the image formed. However I see this effect as negligible since the downwards speed is small. One would instead notice an elongation of the board compared to what is expected by length contraction

Comment: Thank you for your response! Could I confirm that the end of the board of which I am closer to will seem to fall faster?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "would I perceive both ends to fall simultaneously" there are actually two possible interpretations of the time you "perceive" an event: when light literally hits your eye, and what you calculate the original event to have happened after adjusting for the time the light traveled. It is the latter time that is usually of interest. But for completeness there are 4 events in spacetime whose coordinates we can calculate:

(1) The back of the board begins to fall ($B_{fall}$)

(2) The front of the board begins to fall ($F_{fall}$)

(3) Light from the back of the board falling hits your eye ($B_{eye}$)

(4) Light from the front of the board falling hits your eye ($F_{eye}$)

Suppose in the rest frame of the Earth the board has length $L$ and we set the origin at the point in spacetime where the back of the board begins to fall. So the "Earth" coordinates are $(t,x) = (0, 0)$ for $B_{fall}$, and $(0, L)$ for $F_{fall}$.

Let's assume the spaceship is traveling at speed $v$ in the positive x direction, and use the same spacetime point as Earth did as the origin. To calculate spaceship coordinates from Earth coordinates we use the Lorentz transformation $(t', x') = (\gamma(t-vx),  \gamma(x-vt))$ where $\gamma=1/\sqrt{1-v^2}$ (for convenience we are using units where c=1, so length is measured in "light seconds").
In the spaceship coordinates $B_{fall}$ is still $(0, 0)$, but $F_{fall}$ is now $(\gamma(-vL), {\gamma}L)$, which means the times for $F_{fall}$ and $B_{fall}$ are different.

You could do a similar calculation for the events $B_{eye}$ and $F_{eye}$, but you'll have to know exactly where your eye is relative to the board.